# Covariance of the matrix product XC

Tags: probability

If $X$ is an m-by-n iid, what is the simple way to to compute the mean and covariance of $XC$ given $C$ is a deterministic matrix. I found up to $E[XCC'X']$; Can we simply it further?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Can you show your work for $E[XCC'X']$?

Comment: Sure. Cov(XC) = E[XCC'X']- E[XC] = E[XCC'X']- E[X]C = E[XCC'X']. I just want to reduce to some close form if it is possible